# HTML Personal Signature has too many characters. Workaround the 1,333 character limit?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, email-template, html, html5

I tried creating a personal html email signature for a client of ours but the max number of characters it can have is 1,333 but the one I created has much more than that. Does anybody know how I can get around this? I have tried compressing and cleaning up the HTML Code as much as humanly possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to create a custom field on the user object, where you can insert the HTML code and reference it within the signature field?

Comment: How do you go about it? I tried pasting my HTML in a rich text field on the User object but it renders as text only. Doesn't show formatted signature